# What if my field value is blank in an Email Service?

Tags: apex, email, apex-email-service

I just need to be able to handle when a field is left blank. Since the fields aren't required I could have an email without a phone number in the body of the email. Right now I get this error:

> List index out of bounds: 1

How can I fix it?

```
global class CreateLeadEmailService implements Messaging.InboundEmailHandler {

    global Messaging.InboundEmailResult handleInboundEmail(Messaging.InboundEmail email, Messaging.InboundEnvelope envelope){
        Messaging.InboundEmailResult result = new Messaging.InboundEmailresult();
        String leadLastName=email.plaintextbody.split('Last Name: ').get(1).split('Company Name').get(0);
        String leadFirstName=email.plaintextbody.split('First Name: ').get(1).split('Last Name').get(0); 
        String leadCompany= email.plaintextbody.split('Company Name: ').get(1).split('Phone').get(0);
        String leadPhone= email.plaintextbody.split('Phone: ').get(1).split('Email:').get(0);
        String leadEmail=email.plaintextbody.split('Email: ').get(1).split('<mailto').get(0);
        String leadState=email.plaintextbody.split('Region: ').get(1).split('Size of').get(0);        
        String leadProduct=email.plaintextbody.split('Product: ').get(1).split('Plan').get(0);
        String leadPlan=email.plaintextbody.split('Plan: ').get(1).split('Site:').get(0);  
        String leadDes=email.plaintextbody;
        String leadSub=email.subject;
        Integer leadSize=0;     
        List<String> baseSize=email.plaintextbody.split('Size of Customer Base: ');
        system.debug('[CreateLeadEmailService] Size of Customer Base: ['+ baseSize.size() + '] -- ' + baseSize);
        List<String> theSize=baseSize.get(1).split('\\.00');
        system.debug('[CreateLeadEmailService] split on base size: ['+ theSize.size() + '] -- ' + theSize);
        if(theSize.size()>1){
            leadSize=integer.valueOf(theSize.get(0).replaceAll(',',''));
        }

        Lead l=new Lead(LastName=leadLastName, FirstName=leadFirstname, Email=leadEmail, Subject_del__c=leadSub, Description=leadDes, Company=leadCompany, 
                        Phone=leadPhone, Availity_Market_Region__c=leadState, Plan__c=leadPlan, Product__c=leadProduct, Size_of_Customer_Base__c=leadSize );
       insert l;


        if(email.textAttachments != null)
        {
            // Save attachments, if any
            for (Messaging.Inboundemail.TextAttachment tAttachment : email.textAttachments) {
              Attachment attachment = new Attachment();

              attachment.Name = tAttachment.fileName;
              attachment.Body = Blob.valueOf(tAttachment.body);
              attachment.ParentId = l.Id;
              insert attachment;
            }
        }
        if(email.binaryAttachments != null)
        {
            for (Messaging.Inboundemail.BinaryAttachment bAttachment : email.binaryAttachments) {
              Attachment attachment = new Attachment();

              attachment.Name = bAttachment.fileName;
              attachment.Body = bAttachment.body;
              attachment.ParentId = l.Id;
              insert attachment;
            }
        }


        return result;
    }
}
```

Comment: For extracting the data from `email.plainTextBody`, you need to either use regex or add appropriate error handling while parsing email. Right now, you are just assuming and doing a split. Also size check should be done where you use `baseSize.get(1)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Best practice is to check if the list is empty before trying to get the value from index. That will save from exception.

Code should look like

```
String leadPhone= (email.plaintextbody.split('Phone: ').size() > 1) ? email.plaintextbody.split('Phone: ').get(1).split('Email:').get(0) : '';
```

You can refer this for all List Functions: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_list.htm